# Android Sockets programing, accept doesn't accept LAN connections

Tags: android, sockets

```
I am implementing a SocketServer for an Android device.

The device I am using is Samsung G2 I9100.
1. The device is connected to LAN through WiFi
2. The IP returned to the device using 'NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()' & friends is 192.168.2.9
3. The server implementation is as follows:
   java.net.Socket socClient; 
   m_socServer = new java.net.ServerSocket(5050);
   m_socServer.setSoTimeout(0);
   socClient = m_socServer.accept();
4. Connection is accepted When using a local thread to connect eiather to 127.0.0.1:5050 or to192.168.2.9:5050
5. when trying to connect using eg. telnet @ Win7 'm_socServer.accept()' keeps on blocking and the connection timesout on the Win7 telnet session.
6. I have set the 'android.permission.INTERNET' permission.

Why does inproc connection attempts succeed while LAN connection attentps fail? 

Any help will be appreciated.

~Nadav
```

Comment: check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 2):

Several things to check:

1) That you can ping the android device from your win7 box - ie, they are on the same wifi network and it's willing to route packets.  ping 192.168.2.9 *should* work.

2) That you are using a form of the telnet command on windows with is accepting the custom port 5050 instead of the standard one.  telnet 192.168.2.9 5050 *should* work, but you might try grabbing a copy of netcat or putty to use instead of telnet if there's any doubt.

3) That traffic is actually being generated - run a tcpdump-like tool on either the win7 box or if available (or you have root and can add it) the phone and see that there are connection attempts being made to the 5050 port.

4) Normally I would also suggest that you use netstat -n on the phone to verify that you are listening on port 5050 - your in-program tests *seems* to have done that but it wouldn't hurt to be sure.   You can also see if netcat is installed on the phone (as 'nc') and use that from the adb command line for a local connection attempt that's not your program testing *itself*, but that shouldn't really matter.

5) You could also try a different port

6) Make sure there's no firewall on the win7 box blocking *outbound* traffic

7) Make sure there's no firewall or subnet separation on the wifi router blocking traffic between clients on the port you are using, **or between the wired ethernet ports (if that's where the win7 box is) and the wifi clients.**  It's slightly suspicious that your phone's ip address is 192.168.**2**.x - this could imply that your wifi is being run as a separate subnet from your wired Ethernet.

8) Try your program on the emulator using an adb port forward

9) Try somebody else's program that does something similar on the phone, perhaps an ssh server or web server, willing to run on an unprivileged higher port in order to not require root.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed respons, all the LAN machines are of the 192.168.2.* family, another Laptop part of the same wifi network is accessible, As U have advised, I have executed netstat -n on the device, this, shows that the server is listening on tcp6 where I am using tcp4 to connect ( tcp6 0 :::5050 :::* LISTEN ), the Q now, is how can I force the server to liten both, to v4 and v6 IPs ?

Comment: Just tested port forwarding on the emulator as suggested, and the connection was accepted on the emulator... having that in mind, what might cause connection attempts on my Galaxy S2 I9100 to fail? ( .accept() never returns ) ?!?!?!?!

Comment: Maybe see if adb port forwarding on the Galaxy works, where wifi didn't?  But the ipv6 thing may be key - you may need to play with setSocketFactory() and point it at something where you override create() to specify AF_INET in order to explicitly get ipv4.  A search on ServerSocket() and ipv6 results in some mentions of similar trouble on a variety of platforms with some hints of the jdk version possibly matering.

Comment: I was trying to use native sockets programing, the following is a pseudo of what I was trying:
int soc = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
bind(soc, ... )

Comment: adb -d forward tcp:5050 tcp:5050 works! however, still I need to have the WiFi connection working, for that, I was trying to use native sockets to force Ipv4, the following is a pseudo of the code:
int soc=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)
a.sin_family=AF_INET;
a.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
a.sin_port=htons(5050);
bind(soc, ...)
listen(soc, 1)
sockClient = accept(soc, ...)

With that code netstat shows:
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5050 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
Which means that, IPv4 is used and not IPv6, however, telnet still hangs when attempting to connect, AND, the 'listen' method never returns...